# How to login same user in laravel when login in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

Is there any functionality or plugin that login user in laravel when we login in word press. How we intract wordpress with laravel. Both apps use same database.

Comment: is both the application uses Same table as well? I mean is both the application use `wp_users` ?

Comment: yes @RaunakGupta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In WordPress you can use the [`wp_login`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) hook, and trigger an API
>   in laravel with `user_id` and some `secret token` which you can validate
>   in Laravel and if token is correct you can use Laravel inbuilt
>   function to login user by ID i.e,
>   [`Auth::loginUsingId(_USER_ID_);`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#other-authentication-methods), and then you can do your stuff.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for help. I follow this way.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh: don't forget to accept my answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible. The Hampel plugin uses WordPress as your authority,

You can use this library, from Hampel: https://packagist.org/packages/hampel/wordpress-auth-laravel

Might be useful for you.

Comment: is this for laravel or wordpress?